# How to find a basis for a subspace?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

So I have the following subspace

$r − s − 2t − u=0$

$−r + 2s + 5t + 2u=0$

$s + 3t + u=0$

$3r + s + 5u=0$

And I need to find the basis.
I know that  $r,s,t,u$ are all scalars. I was thinking of decomposing these equations into variables and numbers, but i am not sure.

How would i find the basis ? Could somebody help me? 
I was thinkig it might have something to do with the span.

Comment: Maybe you ar elooking for $$r − s − 2t − u=0$$

$$−r + 2s + 5t + 2u=0$$

$$s + 3t + u=0$$

$$3r + s + 5u=0$$

Comment: The exam question was written as i wrote it, all in parenthesis. I am not sure about the zeros. Maybe?